# how to separate xml based on xpath in esql

Tags: xml, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am new to esql.
I have an XML similar to the one given below

```
<vehicles>
  <car make="Ford">
   <model>Mustang</model>
   <year>1965</year>
  </car>
  <car make="Chevrolet">
   <model>Nova</model>
   <year>1967</year>
  </car>
</vehicles>
```

When i give the Xpath as "vehicles/car", I need a function to get two XML as given below as output.

```
<car make="Ford">
  <model>Mustang</model>
  <year>1965</year>
</car>

<car make="Chevrolet">
 <model>Nova</model>
 <year>1967</year>
</car>
```

Thanks in advance.
Biju

Comment: What is the question? (and anyway, should it not be `vehicles/car`?)

Comment: supposedly the question is: What is the equivalent esql? Perhaps `SELECT C.car FROM InputRoot.vehicles as C`? (tbh, I don't know esql that well)

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
//car[1]

//car[2]
```

a nice tool for xpath testing http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/